# Laravel relationships get user emails

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

Hey from my website I'm sending multiple notifications to users, I'm assigning users to a team and then I assign this team to the notifications table.

However when I do `SiteNotification::find(1)->notifications()` then I get the name of the team, however, I was looking to get the user model and all the details related to that. Is there an easy way to obtain this using Laravel Eloquent relationships?

My DB model and Eloquent model are below;

DB tables;

**User**

```
id | username | email
```

**Teams**

```
id | name |
```

**Team Members**

```
team_id | user_id
```

**Site Notifications**

```
site_notification_id | team_id
```

Model Here:

```
class SiteNotification extends Model {

public function notifications()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'site_check_notifications', 'site_check_id', 'team_id');
}

}
```

Update:

I've tried updating the Team Model as follows;

```
class Team extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            User::class,
            TeamMember::class,
            'team_id',
            'id'
        );
    }
}
```

However this throws an error as follows when running this;

```
    $site = Site::find(1);

foreach( $site->notifications as $notification) {
    dd($notification->users);
}

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'team_members.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `team_members`.`team_id` from `users` inner join `team_members` on `team_members`.`id` = `users`.`id` where `team_members`.`team_id` = 4)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I don't understand... You want to retrieve the users related to the team, related to the notification or the users that has been notified?

Comment: @IlGala yes I want to retrieve the users related to the notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution which has meant that I do not need to amend my existing database structure and I've found the correct relationship to use.

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class,
            'team_members',
            'team_id',
            'user_id'
        );

    }
```

Now I can do `Site::find(1)->users->pluck('email')`

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the model structure... This is how I would have reached your goal... Take it as a "working solution", maybe not the best!

First of all, database. You should have these tables, there is no need to

```
users                    => users table
teams                    => teams table
team_user                => pivot table n:n
team_site_notification   => pivot table n:n
site_notifications       => notifications table
user_site_notification   => pivot table n:n
```

Then you create the related models relations

```
public class User {
    // [...]
    public function teams() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class)
    }

    public function notifications() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SiteNotification::class)
    }
}

public class Team {
    // [...]
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
    }

    public function notifications() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SiteNotification::class)
    }
}

public class SiteNotification {
    // [...]
    public function teams() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class)
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
    }
}
```

In your controller, when you create the `SiteNotification` model, you'll have to associate also the users. For example

```
public function store(Request $request) {
   // Do your stuff
   $team = Team::findOrFail($request->your_team_id);
   $notification = Notification::create($data);

   $notification->teams()->associate($request->your_team_id);

   // Retrieve the users from the team... Maybe not everyone should receive a notification
   $team->users()->whereIn('id', $user_ids)->get()->pluck('id')
   $notification->users()->associate($ids);
}
```

When you want to get your users list you simple retrive the associated users in this way:

```
dd($notification->users);

// [ User:{id: 1, '...'}, User:{id: 2}, User:{id: 7} ]
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!